# screen shaking issue on Aframe

Tags: android, aframe

Does anyone have screen shaking issue?

When I use  android phone to browse Aframe.io, some of the demo will be shaking . Some of my friends have the same issue. But some don't.

My Chrome, Line browser, & Firefox Focue mobile browsers have this shaking issue. Firefox mobile doesn't.

Anyone know why it is shaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update to latest A-Frame version (0.8.2) that has a webvr-polyfill which fixes the issue. Here's the link: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3476